# Spinner resets its value when scrolling up

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have a `ListView`, with different custom rows.
The last row contains a `TextView` and a `Spinner`. The `Spinner` works ok (when clicked the dropdown list is shown, when I choose an option it appears in the `Spinner`'s prompt), but when I scroll up the list, the `Spinner` changes its value to the value in the first position (ie the string at position 0).

Why is this happening? And what can I do to stop this?

Comment: can you post the code for the adapter you are using for the listview, and any other pertinent code?

Answer (score 0):

it will its the property create **custonbaseadapter** set **getview** and **newview** method

[Advance List](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive)

[Custom Apdapter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/android-custom-cursoradapter-design)

[See this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)